# ReorderableListView with ExpansionTile

Tags: flutter, drag-and-drop, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a section list view with drag and drop functionality across sections. Is it possible to do this using Flutter widget.

I tried using [`ReorderableListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html) which works fine for drag and drop. But I also want to introduce sections inside my list view. so I tried using `ExpansionTile` instead of `ListTile` inside `ReorderableListView`. but it doesn't seems to be working. Any thoughts on how to implement this.

```dart
class _ItemListWidgetState extends State<ItemListWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    /// iterating through the list items from the store and displaying in a listView.
    return ReorderableListView(
      header: Text('Sample Header'),
      children: widget.model.items.map((Item item) => ListTile(
        key: ObjectKey(item),
        title: Text(item.body),
        leading: Checkbox(value: item.completed, onChanged: (b) {
          widget.model.onCompleted(item);
        }),
        trailing: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
          onPressed: () => _itemsModalBottomSheet(context, () => widget.model.onRemoveItem(item)),
        ),
      )).toList(),
      onReorder: widget.model.onReorderItem,
    );
  }

}
```

The above code works fine for drag and drop but not sure on how to introduce section instead of showing one simple list.